# mysql -> insert into tbl (select from another table) and some default values

Tags: mysql, insert-into

As the title says, I am trying to insert into one table selecting values from another table and some default values.

```
INSERT INTO def (catid, title, page, publish) 
(SELECT catid, title from abc),'page','yes')


INSERT INTO def (catid, title, page, publish) 
VALUES
((SELECT catid, title from abc),'page','yes'))
```

The first query gives a mysql error and the second one gives column count does not match.

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 262, accepted):

You simply have to do:

```
INSERT INTO def (catid, title, page, publish) 
SELECT catid, title, 'page','yes' from `abc`
```

Comment: One important note: you have to put the names of the column from the table where you want to write on the first line, and the column names from the table you're reading go on the second ligne. So in this answer, `catid` and `title` don't point to the same table.

Comment: Another important note: The different types of quotes do different things. \`field\` is a field name while 'value' is a value.

Comment: Notice that the keyword VALUES is not used

Comment: INSERT INTO  offer_masti.`city` (NULL, '1', '1', citydb.city_name, NULL, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) select test.cities.city as city_name from test.cities as citydb;

 i am using this query it give me error can any one help me to solve this error?

Answer (score 12):

If you want to insert all the columns then

```
insert into def select * from abc;
```

here the number of columns in def should be equal to abc.

if you want to insert the subsets of columns then

```
insert into def (col1,col2, col3 ) select scol1,scol2,scol3 from abc;
```

if you want to insert some hardcorded values then

```
insert into def (col1, col2,col3) select 'hardcoded value',scol2, scol3 from abc;
```

Answer (score 12):

```
INSERT INTO def (field_1, field_2, field3) 
VALUES 
('$field_1', (SELECT id_user from user_table where name = 'jhon'), '$field3')
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional [context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. It also doesn't hurt to mention why this answer is more appropriate than others.

Answer (score 8):

If you you want to copy a sub-set of the source table you can do:

```
INSERT INTO def (field_1, field_2, field3)

SELECT other_field_1, other_field_2, other_field_3 from `abc`
```

or to copy **ALL fields** from the source table to destination table you can do more simply:

```
INSERT INTO def 
SELECT * from `abc`
```

Answer (score 3):

With MySQL if you are inserting into a table that has a auto increment primary key and you want to use a built-in MySQL function such as `NOW()` then you can do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO course_payment 
SELECT NULL, order_id, payment_gateway, total_amt, charge_amt, refund_amt, NOW()
FROM orders ORDER BY order_id DESC LIMIT 10;
```