# Duplicate rows in mysql

Tags: mysql

Maybe this seems like the opposite of what people would normally like to do, but I'd like to duplicate rows in my mysql table.

So, for example, I have a table with 1 row that has project_id, and one row with file_name. Each project has very many files associated with it. I would like to duplicate all rows that exist for one project in to another project. I could write some python script that would do this but I suspect there would be a way to do it from within mysql.

Any ideas? Thanks.

For example, if I have a project that looks like this...

```
file_id, file_name, project_id
-------, ---------, ----------
      1, file1.png,          1
      2, file2.png,          1
      3, file3.png,          1
```

...and up to around 100 rows.

What should I type in to get a project that looks like this...

```
file_id, file_name, project_id
-------, ---------, ----------
      1, file1.png,          1
      2, file2.png,          1
      3, file3.png,          1
      4, file1.png,          2
      5, file2.png,          2
      6, file3.png,          2
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample table to show what results you wish to achieve?

Comment: @hjpotter92. Sure, I've added one above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (file_name, project_id)
SELECT file_name, project_id + 1 FROM table_name;
```

This selects everything currently in the table named `table_name` and reinserts the records into `table_name` with an incremented project_id. It assumes the `file_id` field is auto incremented.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I had to adapt it to "SELECT file_name, project_id + 8 FROM table_name WHERE project_id = 1", but it was getiing the answers from SELECT to sit alongside a project_id of 9 that I'd struggled with and it works now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL, you can combine an insert statement with a select statement, such that the values inserted in the new row by the insert statement are the ones selected by the select statement.  See [INSERT..SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html) for details.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like what you need is to INSERT from a SELECT. The basic idea for doing this can be found from the link below.

[mysql -> insert into tbl (select from another table) and some default values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907206/mysql-insert-into-tbl-select-from-another-table-and-some-default-values)

Side note: If you duplicate the rows completely then you will probably have issues with database keys. If you don't, then your database has design issues.

Comment: Thanks, that gave me something to look in to, but I didn't succeed... I'm not sure how to combine the records from the original rows with other values. Do you mind giving me an example? I provided a simplified example of my table above.

Answer (score 1):

I think it can be resolve this way, in case you have a main table that holding the entire project id list, project_table in my example, and assuming that `file_id` in the `file_table` is set to `auto_increment` :

```
INSERT INTO file_table ( file_name, project_id)
VALUES (SELECT file_name, project_table.project_id
        FROM project_table
        INNER JOIN file_table ON project_id = 1
        WHERE project_table.id != 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried Tanvir's solution first because it was simpler, and it worked, so I haven't tried yours. But I appreciate your help.