# Insert into table2 only if a similar record exists in table1

Tags: mysql, pdo

I have 2 tables that are not similar. Is there some way by which I can insert a record into `table2` only if a record with a similar value was found in `table1`? I'm doing all this with `php pdo` and `mysql`

**For Example:**
Lets say `table1` has values like:

```
id
--
1
2
3
4
6
```

**Then:**

```
insert into table2 (id) values (3) // Will work, because id 3 exists in table1
insert into table2 (id) values (7) // Will not work, because id 7 does not exists in table1
```

Right now, the way I do this is to run a `select count(id) where id = 3` and then if a `id` exists, it'll be inserted. Cumbersome!

Is there a way to do this without having to first do a `select` and then an `insert`?

Since this is just the beginning, I'm willing to make changes if something like a `foreign key` etc. needs to be added.

The only query being run here is `insert into table2 (id) values (3)`. And that needs to work only if `id = 3` is found in `table1`. The value `3` is user supplied.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907206/mysql-insert-into-tbl-select-from-another-table-and-some-default-values

Comment: That's quite different. I'm trying to insert a value into table2, only if a row with that id value exists in table1. Not select from table1 into table2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work if `ID` is unique in `Table1`:

```
INSERT INTO Table2 (ID)
  SELECT ID
  FROM Table1
  WHERE ID = 3;
```

If `ID=3` exists in `Table1` you'll get one row inserted. If it doesn't, nothing will be inserted.

If `ID` isn't unique in `Table1` just add `DISTINCT` to the `SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO Table2 (ID)
  SELECT DISTINCT ID
  FROM Table1
  WHERE ID = 3;
```

Comment: Good. I'd go with the first example then. With a unique or PK constraint it will be fast. If you need to insert other values you can just add them as constants to the `SELECT` list, for example: `INSERT INTO Table2 (ID, Name) SELECT ID, 'Norman' FROM Table1 WHERE ID = 3`

Answer (score 0):

Create a trigger

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE
DEFINER = CURRENT_USER
TRIGGER `table2_check` BEFORE INSERT
ON table1
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
if exists (select id from table1 where id = new.id) then
    insert into table2 (id) values (new.id);
end if;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```