# MySQL insert into table with a set of values

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to insert a table with some values (eg: 'NDA' in this case). This seems to work well if I have just one value to be inserted. I have around a dozen of similar values, is there a was i can tweak this query to insert say { 'NDA', 'SDM', 'APM' } values. Was curious to know if it can be done without a stored procedure or copy pasting the same statements over and changing the values.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO customer_feature (customer_id, feature)
SELECT c.id, 'NDA' FROM
customer as c
where c.edition = 'FREE_TRIAL';
```

Reference: [mysql -> insert into tbl (select from another table) and some default values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907206/mysql-insert-into-tbl-select-from-another-table-and-some-default-values)

Comment: What is the condition which will produce the values?

Comment: I am not following you.  Any column in MySQL can have a default value specified.  If you don't specify a value for that column on insert, then that record will get the default value for such a column.

Comment: Defaults for varchars? I am not too sure about that. But I guess it's database dependend.

Comment: Anyway: This question is just to unclear. Try to write in a way such that not only you know what you are talking about rather than that everyone knows what you mean.

Comment: After all: Sound more like conditional default values which you could place in a table, definining your condition and your default value. So you could add new defaults whithout modifying too much of your queries.

Comment: @Peter, Mike: Sorry for the confusion by using 'default'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO customer_feature(customer_id, feature)
    select c.id, f.feature
    from customer c cross join
         (select 'NDA' as feature union all select 'SDM' union all select 'APM'
         ) f
    where c.edition = 'FREE_TRIAL';
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon! This is what i wanted.

Comment: The answer clarifies the question.