# To copy a row and insert in same table with a one different value for a field in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to select already inserted data and want to insert same data into same table. Just one field is change .So i have tried something like this but it is 
not working.

```
INSERT INTO TABLENAME (field2, field3,2) 
SELECT field2,field3 FROM TABLENAME
```

Please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql -> insert into tbl (select from another table) and some default values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907206/mysql-insert-into-tbl-select-from-another-table-and-some-default-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mixed up column names with their values. The `insert into` clause use column **names** which determine where the data should be inserted to. In the `select` list you can have column names, constant or calculations:

```
INSERT INTO tablename (field2, field3, field_with_constant_value) 
SELECT      field2, field3, 2 
FROM        tablename
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can you please help for next issue?

Comment: What next issue? If you have another question (as opposed to a comment about this solution), please post it in a separate post.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to specify fieldName in `Insert Query` and In select query you have to specify new value which you want to insert like :

```
INSERT INTO TABLENAME (field2, field3, field4) 
SELECT field2,field3,2 FROM TABLENAME
```

Comment: Thanks for help. It works and next i want to do is "I have two table TABLE1 and TABLE2. Now I want to update value in relational table(TABLE2) with matching a ID of Master table(TABLE1) with another table ID." . How can i do this?

Comment: I can accept answer after 5 mins as per stackoverflow