# inserting selection into a new column

Tags: mysql

I would like to insert a bunch of values from old_table with multiple columns into a new_table with 1 column.

This is how I plan to make a selection:

```
SELECT DISTINCT City FROM old_table;
```

I would like to insert all the values from this selection into a column.

Normally I would use `INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (value1)`, but this is for inserting 1 row. Now I have 10000 rows I want to insert at once. My apologies if this is already answered. I had little success with googling, due to not knowing how to formulate question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907206/mysql-insert-into-tbl-select-from-another-table-and-some-default-values?rq=1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/74162/how-to-do-insert-into-a-table-records-extracted-from-another-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When inserting the results of a query, you don't use the `VALUES` keyword.

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO table_name
SELECT DISTINCT City
FROM old_tabl
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try insert into.... select statement

like

```
INSERT INTO table_name (col_name)
SELECT DISTINCT City
FROM old_table;
```

if you have number of column is same as insert table, you should try blow query

```
INSERT INTO table_name
SELECT DISTINCT City
FROM old_table;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    INSERT INTO def (catid, title, page, publish) 
SELECT catid, title, 'page','yes' from `abc`
```