# mysql insert into table select from another database

Tags: mysql

I have a table named `user` in database named `client`. user has the structure as follows:

```
`fkey`(varchar(100)) | `status`(enum('1','0'))
```

I have another database named `employees` with a table named `employee`
It has a cloumn named `emailid` which has all the data I need.

I want all the emailid column data from employees.employee to be inserted in client.user at fkey column.there is another column status in client.user which needs to be set as 1 .How do I create a query for this.

This is my query but it is wrong.

```
insert into client.user (`fkey`,`status`) select `emailid` from employees.employee,'1';
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907206/mysql-insert-into-tbl-select-from-another-table-and-some-default-values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely it’s wrong syntax . It should be

```
Insert into client.user (fkey,status) select `emailid`, '1' from employees.employee
```