# MySQL UPDATE table matching the equality of ids in different columns

Tags: mysql

Today i want to write a query to automatically copy the value of one cell to another in different tables comparing the equality of ids...
so i have **`x_content1`** table with **`id1`** column and **`title1`** column, i need to copy **`title1`** column into **`x_content2`** table **`title2`** column comparing **`id1`** with **`id2`**

```
UPDATE x_content2
SET x_content2.title2 = x_content1.title1
WHERE x_content1.id1 = x_content2.id2
```

Please, help! =)

Comment: What's this???  The statement won't even run.  Learn to do some research.  Learn to read documentation.  This question shows no effort at all!!!!

Comment: thanks for the answer, @Eric very useful!
This is what i understood from the answers on another questions on stackoverflow.com and tried to give an example of what i want to build. 
for several hours i tried to find in the documentation the answer for my question, and i couldn't. thats why im asking here.
here for example [https://stackoverflow.com/a/19541555/6715731](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19541555/6715731)

Comment: Do `SELECT` first to make sure you get all the necessary info.  Then convert it to `UPDATE`.

Comment: Show your `SELECT`.

Comment: Hey, @Eric! I've updated the query as in the tutorial here [http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-update-join/](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-update-join/)
is it correct now?

Comment: You miss the `JOIN` to the other table.

Answer (score 0):

With the `JOIN`.  See if this works or not.

```
UPDATE x_content2
JOIN x_content1 ON x_content1.id1 = x_content2.id2
SET x_content2.title2 = x_content1.title1
```